# Binding single key (such as 'F1') to multiple keys (such as 'Ctrl+C') in Gnome

Tags: linux, xorg, gnome

I know how to map a single key to a command using the gconf settings. I also know how to map a single key to another key (<kbd>F1</kbd> -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>) using Xmodmap. My question is how can I map a single key such as <kbd>F1</kbd> to a multi-key operation such at <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I am basically trying to set up a single key to simulate copy. I can think of two ways to possibly do this:

- Map single key to multiple keys so that when the single key is pressed it is essentially pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
- Use gconf settings to execute the copy “command” upon the single key press. I am not sure if there is a “command” to copy text.

Comment: Do you want F1 to act like Ctrl+C everywhere? Or do you want F1 to trigger a copy to clipboard everywhere? Or only in Gnome applications?

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack but I ended up downloading xvkdb and compiling it. I then used gconf settings to bind my key to "/path/to/xvkdb -xsendevent -text '\Cc'" for copy. To compile you need the Xaw-devel libraries (Xaw3d-devel.x86_64, libXaw.x86_64 OR Xaw3d.i686, Xaw3d-devel.i686)

If anyone here has a more elegant solution feel free to post it.